# regular expression "or" to return only one match

Tags: python, regex

```
regex=re.compile(r"pattern_A(\d+)|pattern_B:(\d+)")
result=re.search(regex,string);
```

I have strings "pattern_A9123213", and "pattern_B490329402", and "no matched string"
the results will be [('9123213','')],[('','490329402')]or [('','')]
How can I get only one element like ['9123213'],['490329402'],and [''].
Thank you!

Comment: This is a bit unclear.  regular expressions don't return lists ...  do you mean `re.findall` ?

Comment: @mgilson true but even findall does not return an empty string in a list.

Comment: I think they are named patterns inside A_pattern, is that it ?

Comment: If you have the list you could just take the first element.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use `r"(pattern_A|pattern_B:)(\d+)"` as your regexp, then grab the second match group (`re.search(regex,string).group(2)`).  This works because the group you're trying to grab is the same pattern (`\d+`) on both sides.  In general, you'd have to use multiple regexes to handle this case.

Comment: @ShirleyCia if Keith helped you, please select this answer as _the_ answer.

Answer (score 0):

re.compile does not return a list.  It returns a compiled regular expression, whose methods may be used to operate on strings.